# Matplotlib: error with "height" in grouped barchart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to produce a barchart with two categories on the x axis and, for each category, 5 different series. I took inspiration from [here](http://emptypipes.org/2013/11/09/matplotlib-multicategory-barchart/), and amended the code as follows:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
%pylab inline

myarray=np.array([['Series1', 'A',45],
           ['Series2', 'A',47],
           ['Series3', 'A',48],
           ['Series4','A',48],
           ['Series5', 'A',49],
           ['Series6','B',39],
           ['Series7','B',37],
           ['Series8','B',38],     
           ['Series9','B',36],   
           ['Series10','B',38]]) 

fig1=plt.figure()
ax1=fig1.add_subplot(111)
space=0.25

slots=np.unique(myarray[:,0])
categories=np.unique(myarray[:,1])

n=len(slots)
width = (1 - space) / (len(slots))

for i,cond in enumerate(slots):
    print "cond:", cond
    vals = myarray[myarray[:,0] == cond][:,2]
    pos = [j - (1 - space) / 2. + i * width for j in range(1,len(categories)+1)]
    ax1.bar(pos, vals, width=width,label=cond,color=cm.Accent(float(i)/n))
```

I keep getting the same error: `ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 2 or scalar`.

It points at: `ax1.bar(pos, vals, width=width,label=cond,color=cm.Accent(float(i)/n))`.

I understand the problem is with `vals` because it should either be a scalar or have length 2, but I don't know how to solve it. The elements of `vals` are float!

Comment: My bad. It's now been changed to `myarray`.

Comment: Maybe `Series6` should be `Series1`? and `Series7` should be `Series2` and so forth?

Comment: No, they are different series, and need to be separated. Look at this for clarification: http://emptypipes.org/2013/11/09/matplotlib-multicategory-barchart/

Comment: Why are you generating `pos` with two values (for `A` and `B`)?

Comment: Because they are two different categories. The idea is to have the five bars of category A close to each other, and same for B category bars.

Comment: In http://emptypipes.org/2013/11/09/matplotlib-multicategory-barchart the Series repeats themselves for the three times `rosetta` `rosetta` `rosetta`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

myarray=np.array([['Series1', 'A',45],
           ['Series2', 'A',47],
           ['Series3', 'A',48],
           ['Series4','A',48],
           ['Series5', 'A',49],
           ['Series1','B',39],
           ['Series2','B',37],
           ['Series3','B',38],
           ['Series4','B',36],
           ['Series5','B',38]])

fig1=plt.figure()
ax1=fig1.add_subplot(111)
space=0.25

slots=np.unique(myarray[:,0])
categories=np.unique(myarray[:,1])

n=len(slots)
width = (1 - space) / (len(slots))

for i,cond in enumerate(slots[::-1]):
    print "cond:", cond
    vals = myarray[myarray[:,0] == cond][:,2]
    pos = [j - (1 - space) / 2. + i * width for j in range(1,len(categories)+1)]
    print(float(i)/n)
    ax1.bar(pos, vals, width=width,label=cond,color=cm.Accent(1-float(i+1)/n))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to order the bars according to the progression: red-purple-yellow-pink-green?